# "Eisav is to you tzitzit"

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Bamidbar 15:38

> דבר אל-בני ישראל ואמרת אלהם ועשו להם ציצת על-כנפי בגדיהם לדרתם
>
> Speak to Bnei Yisrael and say to them, "Eisav is to them tzitzit on the corners of their garments, throughout their generations."

Why is Eisav like tzitzit?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Because he was [a good guy](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68077/8775).

Comment: consider marking an answer correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when Bnai Yisrael follow the Torah, and observe all the mitzvos, then they will rise and Eisav will fall. In that case, Eisav would be a "hanger on". As it says in the medrash, the nations will grab your clothing and want to serve you. This is especially true of Eisav, as it says `ורב יעבוד צעיר`

Answer (score 3):

Esav is a lot like tzitzit. Esav was a hairy guy. Hair gets tangled when it's wet. So do tzitzit.

Answer (score 0):

Because he remained on the fringe.

[OTOH, whereas tzitzit are not mechuyav at night, the Esavs that surround us are most dangerous at night (i.e., at a time ch"v of Hester Panim).]

Answer (score 0):

The point of your tsitsit being "עשו" is that they remove divine wrath. We see this since the numerical value of עשו is 376, which in numerically identical to יצא הקצף; the wrath has left.

This reflects the teaching of the Talmud (Menahot 41a) that when God is angry, those without tsitsit may be punished.

> אמר ליה: בזמן דאיכא ריתחא ענשינן

We can infer that the tsitsit diverts God's wrath from those who wear it. (Note that other interpretations of this passage are possible as well).