# PTIJ: "And Eisav is to me a sanctuary"

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In continuation of [my previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80474/eisav-is-to-you-tzitzit) concerning how Eisav is like tzitzit, I have another Eisav-based question on the Torah.

In this week's parsha (Terumah), I became extremely confused on this passuk.

Shemot 25:8

> ועשו לי מקדש ושכנתי בתוכם
>
> And Eisav is to me a sanctuary and I shall dwell in him

Why does Hashem say Eisav is to Him a sanctuary? I always thought Hashem chose Bnei Yisrael as his chosen people, but recently it seems like he really likes Eisav.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

עשו means 'peace', as the numerical value of עשו is 376, the same value as שלום, as noted by [R. Ya'akov Yosef haCohen of Polonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Joseph_of_Polonne)  in Ben Porat Yosef (Parashat Tol'dot):

> כי עשו גימטריא שלום

The intent of peace being God's sanctuary, is that God dwells, i.e. shines his beneficence specifically on the peaceful. This is stated by [R. David Sinszeim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_David_Sinzheim) in Sh'lal David (Parshat V'zot HaBerakha):

> דאימת השראת שכינה כשיש שלום ואגודה אחת
>
> When is the Shekhina active, when there is peace and unity. (Translation my own).

Comment: The numerical value of עשו is 376.

Answer (score 3):

This refers to the final exile - Golus Edom

As in, despite the fact that we are in Galus, G-d will still dwell among us, albeit in a hidden way.

This, explains the Gr'"a in his commentary on Megilas Esther is the great miracle of Purim. That G-d showed that even in exile He is still with the Jewish people.

Answer (score 2):

This is saying that eventually, even Eisav will do teshuvah, acknowledge that yaakov was right, and ask Hashem to dwell with him as He does with Yisrael.

However, this is in Olem Hazeh, as Eisav does not understand the Olam Haemes. As a result, Hashem will have to manifest Himself in this world for Eisav to be able to have a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Did you think for a second that maybe it's because Eisav is the best? Eisav's house is a sanctuary for his holy and revered and awesome father Yitzchak, and he makes all his favorite foods, and only brings in the non-Canaanite wives with the nice names, and all kinds of good things, etc. so why shouldn't it be a sanctuary for Yitzchak's God, too? Is this website anti-Eisav??? I can't believe you people.

Comment: No. This website [is not anti-Esav](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65244/why-does-rashi-describe-mahalath-as-another-unsuitable-wife/68077?s=3|0.1715#68077).